# Is sending attributes as JSON in an POST/PUT request breaking REST?

Tags: json, rest

**TLDR**: is `PUT /users/1` with `user="{name: 'John'}"`, as opposed to `user[name]="John"`, OK?

I love REST. Recently, I find myself storing a lot of my data in client-side JavaScript objects. It seems converting them to form-parameters like

`user[name] = "John", user[login] = "jdoe"`

is unnecessary ugly, since they'll just be reconstructed at the server as something like

`{user: {name: 'John', login: "jdoe"} }`

Advice, Internet? Shall I have the frameworks do the conversion for me? Should I use JSON? Should I start using BSON instead, since it preserves types like Date? :)

Comment: With respect to BSON, only if you can find a BSON parser in Javascript.. which I don't exist (handing of binary data is a royal pain in javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the parameters are in the request body (i.e. not sent as query parameters) and the content type is set appropriately, I don't see there being any problem with it, RESTfully.

Comment: Yup, it's perfectly REST to POST/PUT a representation in any data format in the body of the message as long as the content-type is OK; REST is not about limiting your input resource representations to www-form-urlencoded or multitype-form-data

Comment: Thanks, Carles, that makes me feel a lot better about using it. (Also: you know what the form params format is called? Impressive!)